React-Slick Slider displaying more slides than specified in 'slidesToShow' property
I'm using react-slick for a carousel of YouTube embedded videos. There I have specified the 'slidesToShow' value to 3.
But it is showing more than 3 slides, also the slides are not aligned to centre.
Here is the screen-shot of the carousel:
Image
Here is the code for the page:
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import VideoEmbed from "../video-embed/VideoEmbed";
import VideoData from "../../media/VideoData";
import "./MusicVideos.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

const MusicVideos = () => {
    const settings = {
        className: "center",
        centerMode: true,
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        initialSlide: 0,
        arrows : true,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1000,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    centerMode : false
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 770,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    centerMode : false
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    return (
        <section id="music-videos-section" className="music-videos-section" >
            <div className="music-videos-heading" >
                <h3>Music Videos</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="music-videos" className="music-videos">
                <Slider {...settings}>
                    {VideoData.map(videoId => (
                        <div key={videoId}>
                            <VideoEmbed embedId={videoId} />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Slider>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default MusicVideos;

This is my VideoEmbed code:
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const VideoEmbed = ({embedId}) => {

    return (
        <section className="video-responsive">
            <iframe 
                src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${embedId}`}
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowFullScreen
                title="Embedded youtube"
            />
        </section>
    );
};

VideoEmbed.prototype = {
    embedId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default VideoEmbed;

These are the css-styling that I am using for the Slider class:
.slick-track {
    padding: 3rem 0;
}

.slick-center, .slick-current {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    z-index: 10000;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.slick-list {
    pointer-events: none;
}

What can be the possible cause of this?
Or is there any css property in the Slider class for this?
I have tried changing some css-styles but not able to get any optimal result.

add this css property
overflow:hidden;

to Slider
